# How are featured questions sorted?

Tags: support, bounty, sorting

I have started a bounty for one question two days ago. But every time I check, the question is placed at almost end of the list. So I want to know how the sorting mechanism for featured question works and if I can do something to put my question at top of the list.

Comment: AFAIK it's ordered by expiration date ascending.

Answer (score 2):

Bounties are advertisements. They put a question in the spotlight. Hence the special featured tab. On smaller sites this is not much of problem as there are often less questions to only fill one maybe two pages. On Stack Overflow, with its scale there are always over 400 featured questions.

To give every question a fair chance the questions are ordered by bounty start date in descending order<sup>1</sup>. So the questions that are about to expire are at the top of the list.
You can't influence this in anyway. Only in 7 days time it will slowly rise to the top, while expired bounties are removed, yours will show up at the first page eventually.

Do know that the tag pages also have a link to featured questions for that specific tag. So those that are able to answer and follow their tag on a daily basis will spot your question soon enough.

Although your question gets a bit buried in the list in the initial stages of the featured period the applied sorting logic guarantees every question gets the attention you paid for.

---

<sup>1. I do realize my definition is different from the one suggested by [Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299038/how-are-featured-questions-sorted#comment219368_299038) but given the fact that the [votes table](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/537257#graph) only hold the creationdate for a bounty vote, not the expiration date I think mine is technically more correct. If you find his explanation easier by all means, use that one.</sup>